# ¿Cómo acceder a mi app desde mi celular usando NuxtJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redes

Cuando creo apps con un template usando @vue/cli y ejecuto **vue-client-service serve** me dan una ip de Network y con esa ip puedo accerder a la app desde mi celular.

[image: 'vue-client-servivce serve']

El problema que tengo es que ahora tengo la app en Nuxt y cuando corro el servidor solo me muestra un localhost y no puedo entrar con mi celular ni siquiera poniendo la ip de mi notebook con el puerto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: verificaste que ambos dispositivos se encontraran conectados a la misma red?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que modificar tu fichero `package.json`

```
"config": {
  "nuxt": {
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": "3333"
  }
},
```

De esta manera, nuxt será accesible desde la red de tu equipo. Ahora debes de acceder a la dirección IP de tu equipo por el puerto 3333 (o el que indiques)

Te dejo el enlace a su [documentación](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/)

Comment: Si realizas preguntas, al menos preocúpate de revisar las respuestas. Si ya lo has solucionado indica cómo lo has hecho o simplemente elimina la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

para acceder a la maquina local puedes usar [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)  la ventaja es que te da una direccion web accesible de cualquier lugar, y no solamente desde la red local, con el plan gratis de ellos deberias tener mas que suficiente

Answer (score 0):

También puedes en tu archivo *nuxt.config.js* configurar el server:

```
server: {
  port: 3000, // default: 3000
  host: 'localhost' // default: localhost 'coloca la ip de tu equipo'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para complementar la respuesta de pablote existe un plugin donde peudes exponer tu localhost  co ngrok de manera sencilla sin tener que configurar mucho te dejo el link del plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/ngrok , para testeo veloz es muy efectivo y podras porbarlo realtime en cualquier plataforma.

De manera que al exportar en tus modulos ngrok

```
  modules: [
    // Simple usage
    '@nuxtjs/ngrok',
  ]
```

Cuando compiles en dev mode ademas de la tipica respuetsa de nuxt de Listening on port 3000 tendras algo como esto:

```
> Open http://127.0.0.1:3000
> Open https://starter.ngrok.me for external access
```

donde el segundo enlace sera tu enlace ngrok a tu aplicacion local,cabe destacar que cuando cierres tu servidor local la url de ngrok tambien caera, saludos y espero te sirva de ayuda.